# No device file for connected SAS drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, scsi

I am trying to mount a serial attached SCSI (SAS) hard drive on my Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS system, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding device file in `/dev`. It seems the system is recognizing the SAS controller and the hard drive. What do I need to do to get a device file created so I can mount the drive?

The output of `lspci` shows the controller (a Vinetec LSI00194):

```
$ lspci
...
01:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)
...
```

The output of `lsscsi` shows the drive (the first drive listed is the one I'm trying to mount):

```
$ lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    SEAGATE  ST3146855SS      S513  -        
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST1000DM003-1ER1 CC45  /dev/sda 
[5:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GHB0N    A1B1  /dev/sr0
```

The output of `lsmod` shows that module `mpt3sas` is loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep sas
mpt3sas               221184  0
raid_class             16384  1 mpt3sas
scsi_transport_sas     45056  1 mpt3sas
```

Comment: ave you tried looking at the output of dmesg?

Comment: @edooze: Yes. dmesg shows the controller being recognized (consistent with lspci output above) and mpt3sas being loaded (consistent with lsmod output above).